# If $ isn't x or y

Tags: php, if-statement, comparison

Can't get || to work in this comparison operation and I can't for the life of me understand why.

This works fine:

```
$validation = ($_POST["txtValidcode"]);
if($validation!=='ABC') { $strError .= 'Wrong';}
```

But this doesn't work at all (it treats both entries as wrong):

```
$validation = ($_POST["txtValidcode"]);
if($validation!=='ABC' || 'abc') { $strError .= 'Wrong';}
```

I've tried: or, !=, if($validation!=='ABC' || $validation!=='abc') and probably every other option I could think of. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @executable I've tried that.

Comment: you are trying to check both condition true or wants to check only one true.

Comment: It will show you wrong all the time because the first condition is TRUE !== 'ABC'

Comment: use $validation = strtoupper(trim($_POST["txtValidcode"])); if($validation!='ABC') { $strError .= 'Wrong';}

Comment: @Coder if either

Comment: Change || to && : `if($validation!=='ABC' && $validation!== 'abc') { $strError .= 'Wrong';}`

Comment: @VipinKumarSoni that did the trick! But still, why can't I compare the way I tried to?

Comment: because you can not control front-end user behavior...

Comment: As pointed out, the format is `$var !== 'x' || $var !== 'y'`. However, when using `||` (or), it's enough that _one_ of those evaluate as true for the if-statement to be true, which will always be the case (since a variable can only hold one value).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson And that's exactly what I was trying to achieve. I want it to accept "ABC" or "abc".

Comment: @VipinKumarSoni aha... because of the government? ;) Thank you!

Comment: You're misunderstanding. Your if-statement says "wrong" if the variable __is not__ x __or not__ y. It will _always_ be either __not__ x or y. If it's x, it can't be y. If it's y, it can't be x.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson oooooooh! I basically created a double negative?

Comment: Exactly! :-) That's why you want to use `&&` (and) instead. If it's _not_ x **and** _not_ y. Then both must be evaluated as true for the if-condition to be evaluated as true.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson That made sense, but && still didn't work O_o **<- don't mind me, type-o.** Thanks a lot Magnus for making me understand!

Answer (score 5):

In this case I recommend use `strtolower()` or `strtoupper()` func, for example:

```
$validation = trim($_POST["txtValidcode"]);

if(strtolower($validation) != 'abc') {
   $strError .= 'Wrong';
}
```

or `in_array()`:

```
$validation = trim($_POST["txtValidcode"]);

if(!in_array($validation, ['ABC', 'abc'])) {
   $strError .= 'Wrong';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by *trimming* and making the string to *lowercase*.

```
$strError = '';
$validation = isset($_POST["txtValidcode"]) ? trim(strtolower($_POST["txtValidcode"])) : null;
if($validation !== 'abc') { 
    $strError .= 'Wrong';
}
```